# How to send data to a discord webhook in java using a single .java file?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm working on a Minecraft mod that requires sending a string of data to a discord webhook. What would the most efficient way to achieve this using a singular .java file?

Comment: Use [Discord4j](https://discord4j.com/), you can probably find what you need in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://gist.github.com/k3kdude/fba6f6b37594eae3d6f9475330733bdb) which personally works for me. This is the full code if the gist expire:

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Class used to execute Discord Webhooks with low effort
 * Come from: https://gist.github.com/k3kdude/fba6f6b37594eae3d6f9475330733bdb
 */
public class DiscordWebhook {

    private final String url;
    private String content;
    private String username;
    private String avatarUrl;
    private boolean tts;
    private List<EmbedObject> embeds = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Constructs a new DiscordWebhook instance
     *
     * @param url The webhook URL obtained in Discord
     */
    public DiscordWebhook(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }

    public void setTts(boolean tts) {
        this.tts = tts;
    }

    public void addEmbed(EmbedObject embed) {
        this.embeds.add(embed);
    }

    public void execute() throws IOException {
        if (this.content == null && this.embeds.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Set content or add at least one EmbedObject");
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("content", this.content);
        json.put("username", this.username);
        json.put("avatar_url", this.avatarUrl);
        json.put("tts", this.tts);

        if (!this.embeds.isEmpty()) {
            List<JSONObject> embedObjects = new ArrayList<>();

            for (EmbedObject embed : this.embeds) {
                JSONObject jsonEmbed = new JSONObject();

                jsonEmbed.put("title", embed.getTitle());
                jsonEmbed.put("description", embed.getDescription());
                jsonEmbed.put("url", embed.getUrl());

                if (embed.getColor() != null) {
                    Color color = embed.getColor();
                    int rgb = color.getRed();
                    rgb = (rgb << 8) + color.getGreen();
                    rgb = (rgb << 8) + color.getBlue();

                    jsonEmbed.put("color", rgb);
                }

                EmbedObject.Footer footer = embed.getFooter();
                EmbedObject.Image image = embed.getImage();
                EmbedObject.Thumbnail thumbnail = embed.getThumbnail();
                EmbedObject.Author author = embed.getAuthor();
                List<EmbedObject.Field> fields = embed.getFields();

                if (footer != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonFooter = new JSONObject();

                    jsonFooter.put("text", footer.getText());
                    jsonFooter.put("icon_url", footer.getIconUrl());
                    jsonEmbed.put("footer", jsonFooter);
                }

                if (image != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonImage = new JSONObject();

                    jsonImage.put("url", image.getUrl());
                    jsonEmbed.put("image", jsonImage);
                }

                if (thumbnail != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonThumbnail = new JSONObject();

                    jsonThumbnail.put("url", thumbnail.getUrl());
                    jsonEmbed.put("thumbnail", jsonThumbnail);
                }

                if (author != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonAuthor = new JSONObject();

                    jsonAuthor.put("name", author.getName());
                    jsonAuthor.put("url", author.getUrl());
                    jsonAuthor.put("icon_url", author.getIconUrl());
                    jsonEmbed.put("author", jsonAuthor);
                }

                List<JSONObject> jsonFields = new ArrayList<>();
                for (EmbedObject.Field field : fields) {
                    JSONObject jsonField = new JSONObject();

                    jsonField.put("name", field.getName());
                    jsonField.put("value", field.getValue());
                    jsonField.put("inline", field.isInline());

                    jsonFields.add(jsonField);
                }

                jsonEmbed.put("fields", jsonFields.toArray());
                embedObjects.add(jsonEmbed);
            }

            json.put("embeds", embedObjects.toArray());
        }

        URL url = new URL(this.url);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java-DiscordWebhook-BY-Gelox_");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(json.toString().getBytes());
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

        connection.getInputStream().close(); //I'm not sure why but it doesn't work without getting the InputStream
        connection.disconnect();
    }

    public static class EmbedObject {
        private String title;
        private String description;
        private String url;
        private Color color;

        private Footer footer;
        private Thumbnail thumbnail;
        private Image image;
        private Author author;
        private List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public Footer getFooter() {
            return footer;
        }

        public Thumbnail getThumbnail() {
            return thumbnail;
        }

        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public Author getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }

        public List<Field> getFields() {
            return fields;
        }

        public EmbedObject setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public EmbedObject setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
            return this;
        }

        public EmbedObject setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
            return this;
        }

        public EmbedObject setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
            return this;
        }

        public EmbedObject setFooter(String text, String icon) {
            this.footer = new Footer(text, icon);
            return this;
        }

        public EmbedObject setThumbnail(String url) {
            this.thumbnail = new Thumbnail(url);
            return this;
        }

        public EmbedObject setImage(String url) {
            this.image = new Image(url);
            return this;
        }

        public EmbedObject setAuthor(String name, String url, String icon) {
            this.author = new Author(name, url, icon);
            return this;
        }

        public EmbedObject addField(String name, String value, boolean inline) {
            this.fields.add(new Field(name, value, inline));
            return this;
        }

        private class Footer {
            private String text;
            private String iconUrl;

            private Footer(String text, String iconUrl) {
                this.text = text;
                this.iconUrl = iconUrl;
            }

            private String getText() {
                return text;
            }

            private String getIconUrl() {
                return iconUrl;
            }
        }

        private class Thumbnail {
            private String url;

            private Thumbnail(String url) {
                this.url = url;
            }

            private String getUrl() {
                return url;
            }
        }

        private class Image {
            private String url;

            private Image(String url) {
                this.url = url;
            }

            private String getUrl() {
                return url;
            }
        }

        private class Author {
            private String name;
            private String url;
            private String iconUrl;

            private Author(String name, String url, String iconUrl) {
                this.name = name;
                this.url = url;
                this.iconUrl = iconUrl;
            }

            private String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            private String getUrl() {
                return url;
            }

            private String getIconUrl() {
                return iconUrl;
            }
        }

        private class Field {
            private String name;
            private String value;
            private boolean inline;

            private Field(String name, String value, boolean inline) {
                this.name = name;
                this.value = value;
                this.inline = inline;
            }

            private String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            private String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            private boolean isInline() {
                return inline;
            }
        }
    }

    private class JSONObject {

        private final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        void put(String key, Object value) {
            if (value != null) {
                map.put(key, value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
            builder.append("{");

            int i = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : entrySet) {
                Object val = entry.getValue();
                builder.append(quote(entry.getKey())).append(":");

                if (val instanceof String) {
                    builder.append(quote(String.valueOf(val)));
                } else if (val instanceof Integer) {
                    builder.append(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(val)));
                } else if (val instanceof Boolean) {
                    builder.append(val);
                } else if (val instanceof JSONObject) {
                    builder.append(val.toString());
                } else if (val.getClass().isArray()) {
                    builder.append("[");
                    int len = Array.getLength(val);
                    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                        builder.append(Array.get(val, j).toString()).append(j != len - 1 ? "," : "");
                    }
                    builder.append("]");
                }

                builder.append(++i == entrySet.size() ? "}" : ",");
            }

            return builder.toString();
        }

        private String quote(String string) {
            return "\"" + string + "\"";
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, you have to do something like that:

```
DiscordWebhook webhook = new DiscordWebhook("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/...");
    webhook.setContent("Any message!");
    webhook.setAvatarUrl("https://your.awesome/image.png");
    webhook.setUsername("Custom Usernames!");
    webhook.setTts(true);
    webhook.addEmbed(new DiscordWebhook.EmbedObject()
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setDescription("This is a description")
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .addField("1st Field", "Inline", true)
    .addField("2nd Field", "Inline", true)
    .addField("3rd Field", "No-Inline", false)
    .setThumbnail("https://kryptongta.com/images/kryptonlogo.png")
    .setFooter("Footer text", "https://kryptongta.com/images/kryptonlogodark.png")
    .setImage("https://kryptongta.com/images/kryptontitle2.png")
    .setAuthor("Author Name", "https://kryptongta.com", "https://kryptongta.com/images/kryptonlogowide.png")
    .setUrl("https://kryptongta.com"));
    webhook.addEmbed(new DiscordWebhook.EmbedObject()
    .setDescription("Just another added embed object!"));
    webhook.execute(); //Handle exception
```